# Haskell function composition - two one-dimensional functions to a two dimensional function

Tags: function, haskell, composition

Let's assume I have a function `f` in Haskell, It takes a Double and returns a Double, and I have function `g` that also takes a Double and returns a Double.

Now, I can apply f to g like this: `f . g`.

Now, let's take a higher-dimensional function `f`, that
takes two Doubles and outputs one:
`f :: Double -> Double -> Double` 
or
`f :: (Double, Double) -> Double`
And I have two `g` functions as well:
`g1 :: Double -> Double`, `g2 :: Double -> Double`

Now, I want to compose the functions to get something like:
`composition x = f (g1 x) (g2 x)`

Can this be achieved just by using the dot (.) operator?

Comment: `composition = liftA2 f g1 g2`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2)  for this:

```
composition = liftA2 f g1 g2
```

Since a [function is an applicative [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-973):

> ```
> instance Applicative ((->) r) where
>     pure = const
>     (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
>     liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
> ```

and [`liftA2` is implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#liftA2):

> ```
> liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
> liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x)
> ```

this will thus be resolved to:

```
liftA2 f g1 g2 x = (<*>) (fmap f g1) g2 x
                 = (fmap f g1 <*> g2) x
                 = (f . g1 <*> g2) x
                 = (\fa ga xa -> fa xa (ga xa)) (f . g1) g2 x
                 = (f . g1) x (g2 x)
                 = f (g1 x) (g2 x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import Control.Arrow

composition = f . (g1 &&& g2)
```

`(&&&)` turns `g1 :: a -> b` and `g2 :: a -> c` into `g1 &&& g2 :: a -> (b, c)`. Then you can apply normal composition.